# Вывод данных с таблицы mysql в одну

Tags: php, mysql

Пытаюсь вывести корректно данные из таблицы БД в правильном формате. 
Вывожу данные из -уникальные и их количество.
Необходимо, чтобы они писались в одну таблицу, а не в разные.
Выходит, что согласно скрипту, `echo` выводит каждое уникальное значение в отдельную таблицу, а необходимо сделать это все в одну, добавляя для каждой новой строки новое уникальное значение.

```
<?php 

header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

$db_host = 'localhost';
$db_name = 'selfiepo_kutik';
$db_username = '';
$db_password = '';

$connect_to_db = mysql_connect($db_host, $db_username, $db_password) or die("Could not connect to MySQL server!");
mysql_select_db($db_name, $connect_to_db);

$query=mysql_query("SELECT `utm_campaign`, COUNT(`utm_campaign`) AS cnt FROM `test_table` GROUP BY `utm_campaign`  ",$connect_to_db);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))

{
echo "
<table>
<tr>
<td>".$row['utm_campaign']."</td>
<td>  ".$row['cnt']."</td>
</table>
</tr>"; 

}

mysql_close($connect_to_db);
?>
<code lang="php">
```

Хочу видеть результат в таком виде:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `<table>` и `</table>` вынесите за пределы цикла

Comment: Спасибо, помогли!!

Comment: приходите еще :)

Comment: Не пишите данные подключения к бд. в вопросе

Comment: Ок, я случайно их не удалил. Спасибо.

Comment: @Дмитрий поменять не забудьте, они в истории правок остаются

Comment: Меняйте пароль от греха подальше